# Looking to add a random number to html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a random number generator, but now I need that number to generate when a button is clicked.

I created an HTML element where I would like the generated number to appear:

```
<div class="tag-container">
 <label for="tag" class="l-tag">Tag ID:</label>
  <label class="id"></label>
</div>
```

I created the random generator:

```
let randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
```

I get the elements for the id:

```
let id = document.querySelector("id");
```

create an onclick event for when a button is clicked:

```
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
let addbtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");

addbtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  modal.style.display = "block";
})
```

Not sure how to get the generated ID to populate in the id class, I have thought of using the innerHTML and place that in the click event, but not sure how exactly to accomplish it?

Comment: it will be better to share the complete code in a snippet. there is no button in your HTML code. 
anyway, I added a button and here is the answer:


    let randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    
    let id = document.querySelector(".id");
    let addbtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");

    addbtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    id.innerHTML = randomID;
    })

Comment: Hi, I managed to sort it out, thank you.